# Is there any difference between champion colors?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

Do different colored champions have different bonuses, and, if so, what are they?

I.e. Are green champions the same as red champions?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a carbon copy of the original Legend of Zelda for NES. Strange blast from the past...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've been experimenting for a while with these "Champions".
These are results of my observations:

- different colors have the same stats. I've found 3 [Champion Frowning Gapers](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Gaper) on the same level, each one of a different color. They did double damage(1 heart instead of half) and had approximately double health.  They dropped a penny, a soul heart and a bomb.
- same color doesn't mean same loot. I've found, on the same playthrough, a red [Charger](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Charger) and a red [Vis](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Vis). The first dropped a Tarot, the second a penny. In this same game though, I've dropped another Tarot, but this one from a grey [Pacer](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Pacer).

Naturally these are only examples, I've done a lot more observations of this kind, but these seemed the most relevant.

The general feeling I got from these experiments is that the color is purely aesthetic. It looks like that a champion has Double HP + Double damage + guaranteed random drop (the drop is chosen between those indicated as "Pickup items" in the post [already linked by Raven](http://edmundmcmillen.blogspot.it/2011/09/binding-of-isaac-gameplay-explained.html)). Also the randomness seems to be confirmed by [this Formspring post](http://www.formspring.me/EdmundM/q/295098806947549598) by McMillen himself: the drop is chosen at the moment of death, it's not predetermined.

Comment: I can confirm this.  I found 2 green Globin champions that had the exact same color but different drops.

Comment: Another noteworthy example: same room, 3 champion Chargers, 3 different colors. Drops: bomb, bomb, penny.

Answer (score 7):

Colored enemies are "rare spawns" (or "Champions", if you want to think in Diablo terms). They have a greater chance to drop items on death than their non-tinted brethren, but also have more damage and health.

Officially, this is known as ["Champion Form"](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Champion_Form).

Edmund, one of the devs, briefly discussed this [in one of his development blogs](http://edmundmcmillen.blogspot.com/2011/09/binding-of-isaac-gameplay-explained.html).

> Special enemies will be **randomly colored**, slightly larger then their brothers, do more damage and have more health.

Comment: So is there a difference between the colors?

Comment: Not really. There's some speculation that the different colors have a higher chance to drop certain items (i.e. green usually drop money) but nothing has been proven.
The difference is as Raven Dreamer wrote above, more health and more damage along with a drop.

Comment: @Whettingstone I know the difference between colored vs normal.  I am asking about colored vs colored.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I *believe* it relates to the kind of item they're likely to drop, but I haven't found a corroborating souce for that.

Comment: Some of the champions also have different attack patterns: there's a champion Gurdy that doesn't shoot and only spawns enemies. I *believe*, but cannot prove, that this behavior is dictated by the color.

Comment: @RavenDreamer - I can confirm that color does not correlate between item drops within the same playthrough.

Answer (score 1):

The colored enemies ("Champions") are tougher, sometimes faster or having extra abilities. 
Two different colors will generally have the same abilities, but their drop will be different.

From what I have observed: there is no pattern, as this is random from every new game (Like the pills' effects, it's randomly selected at the beginning). But in a given play, if a green champion drops you a dime, then each subsequent green champion will drop you a "money" rewards.

The types of rewards:

- Money (Nickel, dime, possibly quarter ?)
- Health (Heart, half-heart, soul heart)
- Keys (Keys)
- Bombs (Bomb, 1+1 Free, Troll bomb)
- Activation item (Card, pill)